# Replacing floor joists?

Tags: foundation, joists

The house was built in 1976. It has a crawlspace foundation. There are two joining spans with 13 feet in front, 13 feet in back. A central beam between them.  The front half of the house has water damaged floor joists and the back half has patch jobs probably want to go ahead and fix while doing it. We will be pulling up the subfloor to access under the house anyways in the front half because it is only 24 inches off the ground and the water damage. The house is platform construction like one comment asks.

I just need some advice on how to go about replacing the floor joists. Any advice or suggestions or anything will help. Specifically, I am wondering if I can essentially open up the floor and replace the joists one by one.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is far too broad. You're asking for a substantial carpentry guide to be written for you, covering a wide range of secondary topics, and without any clear view of your project. Please see the [help], take the [tour], and revise to ask a more specific question with supporting information.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Without any pictures or even a drawing, it's very difficult to offer any advice beyond "tear up the floor and replace the joists one at a time".

Comment: FYI, I absolutely agree that this can be a DIY job. You just need to do some homework on basic carpentry first, then come back for assistance. We'd love to help.

Comment: How old is your house?  I assume it's platform construction, where the walls rest on the subfloor, that in turn is fastened to the floor joists?  If that's true, and since you're removing all of the flooring, then I agree with Isherwood that this is an (experienced) DIY project.

Comment: You need to better document your building if you want interesting advice. Is there a strip footing plus wall supporting the floor joists at the exterior walls, for instance? Have you considered removing a chunk of rim board at a time to install joists from outside the house? A bottle jack could provide a sliver of extra space to allow such joists to slide into position.